# Sort with more than 3 Key (7)

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort my worksheet with more than 3 keys.

I have understood that I need to split up my keys, but I do not find anything that works for me.

I want to add this VBA so that it works in any workbook/sheet.

```
Sub Sort()
With Range("A1", Range("AZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 32), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key2:=.Cells(1, 31), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key3:=.Cells(1, 26), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key4:=.Cells(1, 25), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key5:=.Cells(1, 15), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key6:=.Cells(1, 5), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      Key7:=.Cells(1, 4), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With
End Sub
```

Edit: Final VBA-code

```
Sub Sort()

Range("A1", Range("AZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), _
  Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
  Key2:=Range("E2"), _
  Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
  Key3:=Range("O2"), _
  Order3:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

Range("A1", Range("AZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("Y2"), _
  Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
  Key2:=Range("Z2"), _
  Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
  Key3:=Range("AE2"), _
  Order3:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

Range("A1", Range("AZ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("AF2"), _
  Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: The [`Range.Sort` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel) allows for 3 keys which is more than enough for most purposes.  Please include a sample of your data to show how 7 sort keys is possible without the first one getting mixed up by one of the subsequent ones.  If absolutely necessary, sort the "2nd half" first (keys 5 to 7) and repeat, moving towards the main sort key.

Comment: If you're using 2007 or later, record a macro, which will use the `Sort` object - you can have way more than 7 levels with that.

Comment: @ashleedawg I use this since I need to remove duplicates from a data-sample. Not all rows are filled with data in the different cells, and if they do not have data in any of the cells that it is sorted by, it can be removed if it is a duplicate..

Comment: There is only one argument, `Header`, accepted by the sort function, you add it once for every key. Could the problem you are having be caused by including the same argument several times in the function call?

Comment: The way you define the range you want to sort also looks suspect - do you get any errormessages on that line?

Comment: @eirikdaude No problems with using 1-3 keys. And looking online it seems like the Sort function is only working with up to 3 key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem before, I had to sort 8 columns, which I've resolved this way:
(Basically you need to re-sort the selection again and again, starting from the end)

```
'custom sort b d g j m p s v
Range("A4:X757").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("V4"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Range("S4"), _
Order2:=xlAscending, _
Key3:=Range("P4"), _
Order3:=xlAscending

Range("A4:X757").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("M4"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Range("J4"), _
Order2:=xlAscending, _
Key3:=Range("G4"), _
Order3:=xlAscending

Range("A4:X757").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B4"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Range("D4"), _
Order2:=xlAscending
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I expected, but never got it to work. I will have a look and come back if  it does the trick for me :)